# How can I call docker daemon of the host-machine from a container?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container

Here is exactly what I need. I already have a project which is starting up a particular set of docker images and it works completely fine.

But I want to create another image, which is particularly to build this project from the scratch having all the dependencies inside. So, the problem is, when building, to create docker images, we need to access the docker daemon running on the host machine from the building container.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 9):

If you need to access docker on the host from inside a container, you can simply expose the Docker socket inside the container using a host mount (`-v /host/path:/container/path` on the `docker run` command line).

For example, if I start a new `fedora` container exposing the docker socket on my host:

```
$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock fedora bash
```

Then install `docker` inside the container:

```
[root@d28650013548 /]# yum -y install docker
...many lines elided...
```

I can now talk to docker on my host:

```
[root@d28650013548 /]# docker info
Containers: 6
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 530
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
...
```

Comment: This is the better answer. You should be installing docker within the container as the docker installations do change between unix flavors (see the red hat maintained docker vs. the official ubuntu install). Like I mentioned on the other answer, it's beneficial to set these bind mounts as read-only.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: @larsks I have a question, yum -y install docker command is not working, since yum is not presented in ubuntu docker image also apt-get or dpkg is not available. Not sure how to install docker inside the container in this situation :(

Comment: An ubuntu image will typically have `apt-get` available.  All of the official ones do.

Answer (score 2):

You can let the container access to the host's docker daemon through the docker socket and "tricking" it to have the docker executable inside the container without installing docker inside it. Just on this way (with an Ubuntu-Xenial container for the example):

```
docker run --name dockerInsideContainer -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker ubuntu:xenial
```

Inside this, you can launch any docker command like for example `docker images` to check it's working.

If you see an error like this: `docker: error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` you should install inside the container a package called `libltdl7`. So for example you can create a Dockerfile for the container or installing it directly on run:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
apt update
apt install -y libltdl7
```

or

```
docker run --name dockerInsideContainer -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker ubuntu:xenial bash -c "apt update && apt install libltdl7 && bash"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Docker socket has no effect mounting it as read only. Anyway it provides full access to docker daemon.

Comment: Mounting it as ro isn't to limit the access to the docker daemon, it's to limit the access to the host files. This protects against the ability of rm'ing the socket or, in your case, the docker bin file.

Comment: Check this: https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/ <- look the update on the article. As you can see, with access to the docker socket you can get root on host, so it makes no sense.

Comment: I reference that article regularly. What that article is stating is that even with ro, it doesn't prevent a user within that container from spinning up a new container and mounting other host volumes and deleting them. That's an inherent risk of mounting the docker socket in general. The point I'm making is that: If you need to mount something in a Docker container and it doesn't need write access, it should be ro. If not just from a file security perspective.

Comment: If your question is resolved, mark the answer you prefer as solution and/or upvote everything you considered interesting and helped you.